# Azure web app--> The client has disconnected - An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Get below error in Azure web app

.NET FW -> **.NET Core 3.1**

Appy type --> **MVC Core App**

Azure web app configuration --> **.NET 6 LTS**

Other config --> **64 bit , integrated pipeline , HTTP 1.1 , WebSockets OFF , TLS -> 1.2**

### Request Size in around 1 MB.
First 2 requests fail and 3rd request works , This happens intermittently.
All requests pass in first attempt when I run it from local machine
Azure web app is NOT connected to any database or rediscache etc , its doing JSON transformation.

The client has disconnected <--- An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection. (0x800704CD)
[Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: The client has disconnected---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800704CD): An operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection. (0x800704CD)--- End of inner exception stack trace ---at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IO.AsyncIOOperation.GetResult(Int16 token)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadBody()at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContext.ReadAsync(Memory`1 memory, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)at System.IO.Pipelines.StreamPipeReader.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FormPipeReader.ReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.FormFeature.InnerReadFormAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.FormValueProviderFactory.AddValueProviderAsync(ValueProviderFactoryContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.CreateAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IList`1 factories)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.CompositeValueProvider.TryCreateAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IList`1 factories)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

**I tried below setting**
SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT = 600 setting already done
Memory and CPU is in normal limits and there are NO spikes

**I am expecting that all request should work in first attempt**

Comment: This looks like a request timeout, and when the process completes its trying to return the data on a data connection that has timed out and closed.  How long is the request taking before you get this error?  You can check the request in Application Insights, the Logs, and also the "Diagnose and Solve Problems" blade.

Comment: Narthring : request is taking around 2 seconds

Comment: Two seconds is too short to be timing out.  If it takes two seconds and you're getting the "operation was attempted on a nonexistent network connection" it's not a timeout issue.